# Feign & Pageable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, feign

Tell me how to properly configure the work of Feign and Spring Pageable
Here are my Feign settings

```
feign:
  okhttp:
    enabled: true
  autoconfiguration:
    jackson:
      enabled: true
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: ${FEIGN_DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT:10000}
        readTimeout: ${FEIGN_DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT:60000}
        loggerLevel: full
        errorDecoder: ru.core.config.TokenErrorDecoder
        retryer: ru.service.SudisTokenService
```

My FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(name = "BaseCaseFeignClient", url = "${feign.services.host-backend.url}")
public interface BaseCaseFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/api/cases/base")
    Page<BaseCaseEntityDto> getBaseCases(@SpringQueryMap BaseCaseEntityFilter filter, Pageable pageable);

    @PostMapping("/api/cases/base/search")
    Page<FoundRecordDto> searchCases(@RequestBody FilterSpecification filter, @SpringQueryMap Pageable pageable);
}
```

Get request works fine.
Problem with post request.
I am getting the following error

```
"No property caseOpenDttm: DESC found for type BaseCaseEntity!"
```

And in this case, the project is not going to be assembled at all.

```
Page<FoundRecordDto> searchCases(@RequestBody FilterSpecification filter, Pageable pageable);

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page ru..BaseCaseFeignClient.searchCases(ru.ilter.shared.basecase.search.FilterSpecification,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
Warnings:
```

Original request

`http://localhost:8081/cpt/api/cases/base/search?page=0&size=10&sort=caseOpenDttm,DESC`

Instead of such a request

`http://172.24.14.103:30750/cpt/api/cases/base/search?serialVersionUID=1232825578694716871&size=10&page=0&sort=caseOpenDttm,DESC`

Feign sends

```
http://172.24.14.103:30750/cpt/api/cases/base/search?serialVersionUID=1232825578694716871&size=10&sort=caseOpenDttm%3A%20DESC&page=0

http://172.24.14.103:30750/cpt/api/cases/base/search?serialVersionUID=1232825578694716871&size=10&sort=caseOpenDttm: DESC&page=0
```

I found a similar solution https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/146
The problem is that I already have one @RequestBody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated spring-cloud-version to version 3.0.2 helped

Answer (score 5):

In my case, `feign.autoconfiguration.jackson.enabled = true` alone didn't do the trick.

I see the beans are created

**org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @ConditionalOnClass({ Module.class, Page.class, Sort.class })
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "feign.autoconfiguration.jackson.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    protected static class FeignJacksonConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(PageJacksonModule.class)
        public PageJacksonModule pageJacksonModule() {
            return new PageJacksonModule();
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(SortJacksonModule.class)
        public SortJacksonModule sortModule() {
            return new SortJacksonModule();
        }
}
```

but it had no effect on the serialisation.

I had to manually add the two modules in my Jackson configuration

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModules(
                                         new ProblemModule(),
                                         new ConstraintViolationProblemModule(),
                                         new JavaTimeModule(),
                                         new Jdk8Module(),
                                         new PageJacksonModule(),
                                         new SortJacksonModule())
                                 .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                                 .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }
```

Hope this helps